# Recovering my database

Tags: wampserver

Please I really need help here. I uninstalled my WAMP SERVER. And I forgot to export my database before uninstalling, but I successfully copied the my `c:\\wamp` folder. Is there a way I can recover my database from the copied files?

Comment: Yes. Install the same version of MYSQL either using WAMPServer or whatever. Then you can do it.

Comment: Tell us a bit about the database in question? Is it INNODB or MYISAM

Comment: first try 1) stop WAMPServer 2) copying `\backup\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\data` to `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\data` 3) Restart WAMPServer

Answer (score 0):

The database files are in the C:\wamp\mysql\data folder. I would recomend reinstalling the wamp and recovering the database from there.

Comment: Yes, I have reinstalled the WAMP but I don't know how to recover them

Comment: Copy the contents of your backed up C:\wamp\mysql\data folder into the original direction (actual C:\wamp\mysql\data)

Comment: _The database files are in `C:\wamp\mysql\data`_ No they are not

Comment: Thats odd. Try to search for the name of your database in that backup

Comment: They are and have always been in `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\data`

Comment: Why dont you copy them to their origina location?